# Google Maps multiple dropdown filters that work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to filter markers on google maps with two or more dropdown menus. The problem is the dropdown filters do not filter off of each other. When I change the value of one drop down and it filters out the markers, the second filter doesn't filter off of the markers shown from the first filter but all of the markers. any help would be appreciated!

JS:

```
//global variables
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

//add the shipwreck data
markers1 = [
  ["Name","Latitude","Longitude","Year","Type","Type_of_Loss"  ],
  ["Bermuda","46.46483333","-86.64683333","1870","Schooner","Storm"  ],
  ["George","46.516","-86.52083333","1893","Schooner","Storm"  ],
  ["Herman H. Hettler","46.48383333","-86.59966667","1926","Propeller","Storm"  ],
  ["Kiowa","46.64516667","-86.22016667","1929","Propeller","Storm"  ],

];


//initiate the map
function initMap() {
    // Our markers


    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4357808, 4.991315699999973);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };



    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }

}


//add markers to the map
function addMarker(marker) {    
    var category_type = marker[4];
    var category_loss = marker[5];
    var category_year = marker[0];
    var title = marker[0];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[1], marker[2]);
    var content = marker[0];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        //setup the categories for the different mark types
        category_type: category_type,
        category_loss: category_loss,
        category_year: category_year,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}


//filter the markers by type of ship
filterMarkers = function (category_type) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category_type == category_type || category_type.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

//filter the markers by type of loss
filterMarkers2 = function (category_loss) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category_loss == category_loss || category_loss.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }

    }
}

// Init map
initMap();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="sidebar col-xs-3">
                        <h2>Filter Shipwrecks</h2>
                        <div class="filter-options">
                            <div class="filter-set" style="margin-top:0;">
                                <button id="load-btn" class="load-btn button is-success">Reload data</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="filter-set">
                                <label for="ship-select">Ship Type:</label>
                                <select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
                                <option value="">Any</option>
                                <option value="Barge">Barge</option>
                                <option value="Freighter">Freighter</option>
                                <option value="Propeller">Propeller</option>
                                <option value="Schooner">Schooner</option>
                                <option value="Steamer">Steamer</option>    
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="filter-set">
                                <label for="ship-select">Type of Loss:</label>
                                <select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers2(this.value);">
                                <option value="">Any</option>
                                <option value="Collision">Collision</option>
                                <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
                                <option value="Intentional">Intentional</option>
                                <option value="Storm">Storm</option>                                   
                            </select>
                            </div>
```

Comment: I guess your filtering functions – those called in `onchange` events – should consider the values of both `<select>` elements.

Comment: I am filtering map markers using 2 functions and 2 dropdown menus. Using the second dropdown menu should further narrow the results from the first, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, you may fix the filtering issue by considering the values of both `<select>` elements.

You can achieve that by having a single filtering function, like this:

```
filterMarkers = function () {
    var category_type = document.getElementById('category_type_filter').value;
    var category_loss = document.getElementById('category_loss_filter').value;
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        if ((
            marker.category_type == category_type ||
            category_type.length === 0
        ) && (
            marker.category_loss == category_loss ||
            category_loss.length === 0
        )) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
};
```

If you compare this with your functions, you'll see the condition to set a marker as "visible", is now the combination of both filters.

In your HTML, add an `id` attribute to each `<select>`, using the same values from the function: `category_type_filter` and `category_loss_filter`.

That should do the trick.

Just to be clear, your issue is not related to Google Maps but to Javascript, in general. Maybe it's a good idea to spend some time reading about how DOM, events, and Javascript can work together. :)

P.S.: For conciseness, you can even replace the entire `if`/`else` block by a single function call:

```
marker.setVisible((marker.category_type == category_type || category_type.length === 0) && (marker.category_loss == category_loss || category_loss.length === 0));
```

Comment: Worked great. Sorry, I am still learning. I do appreciate the help.